# SQL search name and sort by best fit

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

I have a website with shops database. Visitor of my website is able to search shops by name, currently the SQL query is done like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_shop 
WHERE LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%text1%`) 
   OR LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%text2%`) 
   ..... 
   OR LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%textN%`)
```

This works quite ok, but the problem is, that results are not sorted by best match. Some shop names contain very common words (eg. "Na Lavce") and if you enter this string, all salons which contain "%na%" (which is a lot) are displayed as results.

Because of this, visitor can get many results and sometimes is not able to find, what he is looking for, because the proper result is for example on 5th results page. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You could easily rank them by the number of matches and you could also assign preference to the order of the terms. But how else will you know which one is better?

Comment: You could also set a list of common words and avoid searching those words, but that would require a bit of preprocessing.

Comment: Many common words are also shorter words. You could rank by the length of the search terms in some fashion but I didn't say this at first because I'm not sure it's reliable.

Comment: most databases support `fulltext` matching, which sounds like what you're trying to implement

Comment: yes, ranking by number of matches or fulltext are good ways, but how to implement it? do you have any code example?

Comment: Why not use a drop down (with auto-select functionality) to limit the list for users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_shop 
WHERE 
       LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%text1%`) 
   OR  LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%text2%`) 
   ..... 
   OR  LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%textN%`)
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%text1%`) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%text2%`) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   .....
   CASE WHEN LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%textN%`) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   DESC
```

If you wanted to rank by order of terms:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%text1%`) THEN 1024 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%text2%`) THEN  512 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%text2%`) THEN  256 ELSE 0 END +
   .....
   CASE WHEN LOWER(`name`) LIKE LOWER(`%textN%`) THEN    1 ELSE 0 END
   DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it now. Order of terms is random (visitors enter them) so it is probably not for me right?

Comment: I found out, that sorting is done in my application by attribute (order of returned rows is ignored), so I need to add the rank to the query results... Is possible somehing like this?

`SELECT *, 
(CASE WHEN LOWER(  `name` ) LIKE LOWER(  '%text1%' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN LOWER(  `name` ) LIKE LOWER(  '%text2%' ) THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END) AS order 
FROM tbl_salon
WHERE LOWER(  `name` ) LIKE LOWER(  '%text1%' ) 
OR LOWER(  `name` ) LIKE LOWER(  '%text2%' ) 
ORDER BY order`

this one has syntax error, but I am looking for something similar

Comment: Try a different name. "order" is a reserved word and you need it in quotes if you really need to use it that way.

Comment: I wouldn't say the order is "random". But users would have to know the significant of the terms in the search criteria and it may not be reasonable to expect the to do it that way.

Comment: I tried different word then "order" and it worked. Thank you:-)
Final code looks like:

SELECT *, 
(CASE WHEN LOWER( `name` ) LIKE LOWER( '%text1%' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN LOWER( `name` ) LIKE LOWER( '%text2%' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS something
FROM tbl_shop WHERE LOWER( `name` ) LIKE LOWER( '%text1%' ) OR LOWER( `name` ) LIKE LOWER( '%text2%' ) ORDER BY something DESC;